# Yii createCommand() return data set in different array format

Tags: php, yii

I'm a beginner in this framework. Though I have gone over the basics, there is one thing which is troubling me. As of now, I'm using

```
$group_sql = "SELECT uid FROM {$table}";
$group_users = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($group_sql)->queryAll();
print_r($group_users);
```

results in

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [uid] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [uid] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [uid] => 4
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [uid] => 5
        )

)
```

But I'd like to change the format in which the data is returned. What I'm looking for is something like

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 4
    [3] => 5
)
```

OR

```
Array
(
    [uid] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 4
            [3] => 5
        )
)
```

I'm aware that I can go through the documentation and get my answer, but due to time constraints, I'm taking the liberty to shamelessly ask this over here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `queryColumn()` method instead of `queryAll()`

Comment: Bingo! +1 and will accept as answer when the time limit wears off.

Comment: If it's not much trouble, can you point me to the link where these methods have been documented so that I can go through them and see what other options I can use in future?

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand here is all you need regarding CDbCommand class. Similar methods are queryAll(), queryColumn(), queryRow(), queryScalar()